# PHP in javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

in my .js file i have a line.

```
var sidebarWidth = 120;
```

I need the the number above to be dynamic, so i users can change it in admin panel. I have created the php options page.
How do I access php variable in javascript file?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of including js file you can localize script and set it to that js file and access it from js file like this

```
<?php
    wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

    // Localize the script with new data
    $translation_array = array(
        'sidebarWidth' => 'your_value'
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

js file

```
alert( object_name.sidebarWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript file is static, so you will need to print your variables to the page and then read them from your script. Take care to set the variables before they are accessed by your script - either above the script include, or use `jQuery.ready()` to run code after the DOM loads.

The best place to output your variables is in the `wp_head` action.

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'dynamic_js_variables_33726359', 1 );
function dynamic_js_variables_33726359(){
    // output your dynamic variables, they will be global
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var sidebarWidth = '<?php echo $sidebar_width; ?>';
    </script>
    <?php

    // enqueue your javascript file
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script', $src, $deps, $ver );
}
```

Then you can use the variable within your javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // alert the global sidebarWidth variable value
    alert('The sidebarWidth is ' + sidebarWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var sidebarWidth = '<?php echo $user_width; ?>';
</script>
```